# call a method in map and lambda using dictionary as input in python

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

```
test_input = {"oneone": 1, "twotwo": 2, "threethree": 3}

def testmethod(no):
    print(f"Number {no}")
    return True, f"Number {no}"
```

Without using `lambda` and `map`:

```
d = {}
for k, v in test_input.items():
    ret, out = testmethod(v)
    if ret:
        d[k] = out
```

I tried below line to iterate using `lambda` and `map`:

```
>>> dict(map(lambda ref: testmethod(ref), list(test_input.values())))
{True: 'Number 3'}
```

Expected output using `map` and `lambda`:

```
{'oneone': 'Number 1', 'twotwo': 'Number 2', 'threethree': 'Number 3'}
```

Comment: `testmethod()` is always returning `True` as the first element of the tuple. You are using this value as the key in the dictionary, and you are overwriting the corresponding dictionary value at each iteration.

Comment: @bb1. You're not overwriting: it's a new dictionary. Also, pretend it's just an example

Comment: @MadPhysicist The dictionary is new, but it is built by iterating over tuples `(True, some_value)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite your loop as follows:

```
d = {}
for k, v in test_input.items():
    tup = testmethod(v)
    if tup[0]:
       d[k] = tup[1]
```

The key is that packing and unpacking the two return values is distracting you from the fact that they are actually one return value.

Combine this insight with the walrus operator to merge the assignment and conditional lines:

```
if (tup := testmethod(v))[0]:
```

Now you have something shaped like a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {k: tup[1] for k, v in test_input.items() if (tup := testmethod(v))[0]}
```

If you have an older version of python (pre-3.8), or want to avoid using the walrus for some other reason, you need to filter the result. Your `lambda` is misplaced: `lambda ref: testmethod(ref)` is just `testmethod` with extra steps. The trick is to split the streams after you did the mapping. You can then filter with something like [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
from itertools import compress

rets, outs = zip(*map(testmethod, test_input.values()))
d = dict(compress(zip(test_input.keys(), outs), rets))
```

This is a fairly ugly and inefficient two-liner. You can make it a lot worse as a one liner. To do that, you turn `rets, outs` into a list, reverse it, and expand it into a zip after `test_input.keys()` to make an iterator that yields `key, value, filter`:

```
d = {k: v for k, v, tf in zip(test_input. keys(), *list(zip(*map(testmethod, test_input.values())))[::-1]) if tf}
```

Comment: @Barmar. Assuming that filtering is required, a non-walrus comprehension is possible, but boy is it ugly